# c++ printf float - how to specify precision programmatically?

Tags: c++, printf

`printf("float: %.3f", myvar);` prints myvar with 3 digits after the dot. But how can I do that if the number of digits I want to print is dynamic and specified in an int variable?

Comment: The format string doesn't have to be a string literal. You can write your own format string in a `char` array on the fly. (I'd have written an answer with code to demonstrate this, but there's already an accepted answer, so I'm not going to waste my time)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `%.*f` and add the `int` value before the data to print.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {
    double myvar = 3.141592653589;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("float: %.*f", i, myvar);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: great, and for potentially other values to substitute in the string it remains one parameter? for example: `printf("%s%.*f%s", "float: ", i, myvar, " $");` ?

Answer (score 3):

To be more into modern c++, and as alternative to
MikeCAT response

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    constexpr int precision = 2;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision( precision ) << 10.1234 << std::endl; // outputs: 10.12
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `setprecision` is to old to be called "modern c++".

Comment: whoa, didn't know about it, what's new. It seems i am out of date @MarekR

Comment: `fmt` will become part of C++20 standard this will be more handy (short as `C` version and type safe).

Comment: Looks, [NOIZZ](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)